# Hydrate a tree from a table

Tags: c#, database, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have a DataTable with all of my nodes in it.  They were serialized to database.  I want to create an object graph (hierarchical) representation of the data.  There seem to be a few methods for doing this.

[This article describes a high order method](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/118395) (meaning it involves lots of searching of the DataTable before the tree is fully built)

**Is there an Order-N approach?**  In my case, I have pre-sorted the nodes of the tree in the DataTable into the in-order form.  Meaning, the first row shows a NULL for the parent, because it's the root.  Each subsequent row is sorted in [in-order notation](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/6358).

I seem to recall an Order-N approach from my school days. But I can't remember.

My DataTable schema resembles this:

- NodeID - int
- ParentNodeId - nullable
- Data - string

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444296/how-to-efficiently-build-a-tree-from-a-flat-structure  That uses a dictionary to keep track of the parent nodes, and is probably the easiest way to do it. I've used a recursive solution that doesn't require a dictionary, but it's been so long I'd have to derive it again.

Comment: That doesn't look like in-order form. If that were the case, root wouldn't be the first node in the table. Did you mean pre-order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an algorithm that should do what you need it to do. It assumes your data is in order, so it performs in O(n).

First, you need a node that looks like this:

```
class Node {
    Node Parent;
    List<Node> Children = new List<Node>();
    int NodeId;
    string Data;
    public Node(NodeRow row) { ... }
}
```

1. Load first row as `current`.
2. Load next row; compare `newRow.ParentNodeId` to `current.NodeId`.
3. Until you find a match, set `current = current.Parent`
4. Add the `newRow` to `current.Children` and set `current` to the new row.
5. Go to step 2.

That's it!  If your data is guaranteed to be structured correctly, then you won't need to do any extra `null` checks.

Sample:

```
Node CreateTree(IEnumerable<NodeRow> rows) {
    Node root = null;
    Node current = null;
    foreach (var row in rows) {
        // Root:
        if (root == null) { 
            root = current = new Node(row);
            continue;
        }
        // Traverse up the tree until the parent is found:
        while (row.ParentNodeId != current.NodeId) {
            current = current.Parent;
        }
        // Add the new node as a child of the current one:
        var rowNode = new Node(row);
        rowNode.Parent = current;
        current.Children.Add(rowNode);
        current = rowNode;
    }
    return root;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Got a little issue.  In the Node class, you've got Parent listed as a fully formed Node.  All I have is the Parent's ID.  In order to fully form the parent Node, I have to perform a search of the DataTable for each Node.  So we're back to that again -- extra lookups.   What's coming from my database is a column that tells me the Parent's ID.  The rows are in-order.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a line: `rowNode.Parent = current;`.  For each new row, we traverse up the tree, looking for a matching `ParentNodeId`.  Then, the new `rowNode.Parent` is set to `current`.

Comment: ... Since the data is "in-order", we know that the `ParentNodeId` must match one of `current`'s ancestors.  That's what gives us `O(n)`!