# Creating Recursive Object from flat list

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, serialization

I have a list as you see below:

```
        List<MenuItem> menuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
        menuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { SiteMenuId = 1, ParentId = null, MenuName = "Menu", Url = null, SiteId = 1 });
        menuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { SiteMenuId = 2, ParentId = 1, MenuName = "aaa", Url = "aaa", SiteId = 1 });
        menuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { SiteMenuId = 3, ParentId = 1, MenuName = "bbb", Url = null, SiteId = 1 });
        menuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { SiteMenuId = 4, ParentId = 3, MenuName = "ccc", Url = "ccc", SiteId = 1 });
        menuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { SiteMenuId = 5, ParentId = 3, MenuName = "ddd", Url = "ddd", SiteId = 1 });
        menuItems.Add(new MenuItem() { SiteMenuId = 6, ParentId = 1, MenuName = "eee", Url = "eee", SiteId = 1 });
```

Is it possible to translate this data structure to a format that can be serialized as the following json:

```
{
    "Menu": {
        "aaa": "aaa",
        "bbb": {
            "ccc": "ccc",
            "ddd": "ddd"
        },
        "eee": "eee"
    }
}
```

If the answer is yes, how can I do that?

Comment: Perhaps you could suuply some sample code and rephrase your question as "Here's what I tried why doesn't it work?". This is a "Give me the codez" question that isn't partiularly suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @PaulHicks Did you read the answer/s for this question? You know that there is a generic response to these kinds of questions, But if you read my comments for the answer you will see that this is not my expectation. Anyway thanks for your effort for writing this kind of helpfull comment.

Comment: Yes, there are [generic answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) that are very suitable for tutorial websites, Yahoo! Answers, and other places. This site prefers [specific questions with specific answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Json.NET serializes any [`IDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to a [JSON key/value pair object](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDictionary.htm) - but converting to a `Dictionary<string, object>` then serializing would be problematic because the .Net dictionary is [unordered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384710/why-is-a-dictionary-not-ordered), and you (probably) want to *preserve* the relative order of the `MenuItem` objects when serializing to JSON.  Thus it makes sense to manually convert to a tree of [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) objects using [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) since Json.NET preserves order of object properties.

Thus you would do:

```
    public static string CreateJsonFromMenuItems(IList<MenuItem> menuItems)
    {
        return new JObject
        (
            menuItems.ToTree(
                m => (int?)m.SiteMenuId,
                m => m.ParentId, m => new JProperty(m.MenuName, m.Url),
                (parent, child) =>
                {
                    if (parent.Value == null || parent.Value.Type == JTokenType.Null)
                        parent.Value = new JObject();
                    else if (parent.Value.Type != JTokenType.Object)
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("MenuItem has both URL and children");
                    child.MoveTo((JObject)parent.Value);
                })
        ).ToString();
    }
```

(Note this method throws an exception if a `MenuItem` has both a non-null `Url` and a collection of children.)

It uses the following extension methods:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static void MoveTo(this JToken token, JObject newParent)
    {
        if (newParent == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var toMove = token.AncestorsAndSelf().OfType<JProperty>().First(); // Throws an exception if no parent property found.
        if (toMove.Parent != null)
            toMove.Remove();
        newParent.Add(toMove);
    }
}

public static class RecursiveEnumerableExtensions
{
    static bool ContainsNonNullKey<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        return key == null ? false : dictionary.ContainsKey(key); // Dictionary<int?, X> throws on ContainsKey(null)
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TResult> ToTree<TInput, TKey, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TInput> collection,
        Func<TInput, TKey> idSelector,
        Func<TInput, TKey> parentIdSelector,
        Func<TInput, TResult> nodeSelector,
        Action<TResult, TResult> addMethod)
    {
        if (collection == null || idSelector == null || parentIdSelector == null || nodeSelector == null || addMethod == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var list = collection.ToList(); // Prevent multiple enumerations of the incoming enumerable.
        var dict = list.ToDictionary(i => idSelector(i), i => nodeSelector(i));
        foreach (var input in list.Where(i => dict.ContainsNonNullKey(parentIdSelector(i))))
        {
            addMethod(dict[parentIdSelector(input)], dict[idSelector(input)]);
        }
        return list.Where(i => !dict.ContainsNonNullKey(parentIdSelector(i))).Select(i => dict[idSelector(i)]);
    }
}
```

Working [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kCeeA2).

Comment: Thanks for your great answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to Create a class like this

```
public class MenuItemTr
{

 public MenuItemTr
 {
    this.MenuItems= new List <MenuItem>
 }
public int SiteMenuId {get; set;}
public int ParentId {get; set;}
public string MenuName {get; set;}
public string Url {get; set;}
public int SiteId {get; set;}
public List <MenuItemTr> MenuItems {get; set;}
}
```

and then parse it to a tree

```
var MenuItem = menuItems.GenerateTree(c => c.SiteMenuId, c => c.ParentId);
```

and use this solution from this thread [Nice & universal way to convert List of items to Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648166/nice-universal-way-to-convert-list-of-items-to-tree)

```
public static IEnumerable<TreeItem<T>> GenerateTree<T, K>(
        this IEnumerable<T> collection,
        Func<T, K> id_selector,
        Func<T, K> parent_id_selector,
        K root_id = default(K))
    {
        foreach (var c in collection.Where(c => parent_id_selector(c).Equals(root_id)))
        {
            yield return new TreeItem<T>
            {
                Item = c,
                Children = collection.GenerateTree(id_selector, parent_id_selector, id_selector(c))
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But this object will not be serialized as expected in the question?

Comment: I need a json transformation to the same format that explained in question. By serializing the MenuItemTr object you will have MenuItems:[] part in json.